# What's the easiest way to emulate a post request from unix cmdline?

Tags: post, curl

My job has a reservation system that requires me to periodically go to a particular page and do a refresh. When a seat becomes available, I can then reserve on a first come first served basis.

I want to write a script that will email/text me when something becomes available. To do this I need to emulate clicking in the browser.

I know that the page is an aspx script with post requests.

Is there some way to log clicking on the "go" button, dump that to a file and transform that into a curl command. In chrome, I can dump a HTTP Archive file. Perhaps there are other paths. I can run explorer or firefox too.

Answer (score 1):

You
[can use curl](http://github.com/svnpenn/a/blob/29d84bd/scripts/github-api.sh)
with the `POST` verb

```sh
curl -X POST -u svnpenn -k \
  -d '{"name":"tcl-8.5.13.tar.gz","size":130073}' \
  https://api.github.com/repos/svnpenn/etc/downloads
```